# bind9 starting with boot

Tags: boot, services, init.d

How to add `bind9` to start with Ubuntu boot? I search a lot and didn't find anything useful.

Maybe something related to `init.d`, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try with command to add `bind9` to startup `sudo update-rc.d bind9 defaults`

You can check result with command `sudo bind9 status`
Also you can see list services that start on startup with command `initctl list`